# Replace certain character on string from an array of string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have a string like this

```
const text = 'hello ___ where ___ test ___'
```

And also an array like this

```
const blankData = ['there', 'you', 'it']
```

my expected result is

```
hello there where you test it
```

what i have tried

```
const result = text?.replaceAll('___', (index, x) => {
    return blankData[index]
  })
```

I also getting with not ellegant idea like this

```
const mapped = text
    .split('___')
    .map((textitself, index) => textitself + blankData?.[index])

  mapped.pop()

 const result = mapped.join('')
```

is there better solution?

im thinking of getting the index so i can replace for every index found but replace fould not getting index from it callback

Answer (score 2):

You could globally match `___` using the `/g` flag and get the index of the replacement from `blankData` be seeding a start value of 0 and increment it in every iteration.

```js
const text = 'hello ___ where ___ test ___';
const blankData = ['there', 'you', 'it'];

result = text.replace(/___/g, (i => _ => blankData[i++])(0));

console.log(result);
```

**Note** that if you don't want to have multiple matches for `_________` but also don't want to match  a single `_` you can use `_{3,}` as the pattern to match 3 or more times an underscore.

```js
const text = 'h_ello ______ where ___ test ___';
const blankData = ['there', 'you', 'it'];

result = text.replace(/_{3,}/g, (i => _ => blankData[i++])(0));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: blankData[i++](0) what the (0) means

Comment: @BryanLumbantobing The callback of replace takes a function. We can specify a function that returns a function where `i` is initialized with 0 and increments every time the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) here, You can declare `index` outside of the `replace` or `replaceAll` method.

You have hardcoded the replacement string `___`, What if there is one more `_` so you can make it generic with using quantifiers `_+` which is `one or more _`

[image]

```js
const text = "hello ___ where ___ test ___";
const blankData = ["there", "you", "it"];

let index = 0;
const result = text.replace(/_+/g, () => blankData[index++]);

console.log(result);
```

You can also use replaceAll but you just have to take care of the index

```js
const text = "hello ___ where ___ test ___";
const blankData = ["there", "you", "it"];

let index = 0;
const result = text?.replaceAll("___", () => {
  return blankData[index++];
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: not understand the regex why is _+. why dont just ___ insted inside the global regex. don't know this increment index before btw thanks

Comment: ou have hardcoded the replacement string ___, What if there is one more `_` so you can make it generic with using quantifiers `_+` which is `one or more _`

Comment: try to run your code with `"hello ___________ where ___ test ___"`

Answer (score 1):

I already made a function for that. I think the code is self-explanatory.

```js
function injectStrings(string, replacementsArr) {
  var pattern = /___/g,
      replacement = '';

  return string.replace(pattern, function(match) {
    replacement = replacementsArr.shift();

    if (typeof replacement == 'number' || typeof replacement == 'string') {
      return replacement;
    }

    // console.log('parameter for ' + match + ' is missing in \"' + string + '\"');

    return '';
  });
}

const text = 'hello ___ where ___ test ___'
const blankData = ['there', 'you', 'it']

// output: And also an array like this
console.log( injectStrings(text, blankData) );
```